# button onclick using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I need to add a button to my Form in which if I click that button it should show me a text area and a Submit button so after typing any text I will click the submit button it should print the checkbox in my form using AngularJS.
[image]

Same as in the above pic. I am new to typescript so help me to fix this

Comment: typescript is just a programming language. How to do this depends entirely on the frontend framework/lib you are using, e.g. react, angular, jQuery, ...

Answer (score 1):

Use the ngClick directive:

```
<button ng-click="yourFunction()">OK</button>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick

Also, please read the documentation or a tutorial/example before you ask such a basic question...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19398778)

Comment: I have provided the essential part. I also pointed him in the direction where he can find more information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-ng-controller="homeController">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="cursor:hand" aria-hidden="true" title="Add More" ng-click="onEnable()"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="text" ng-if="isEnableTextBox" ng-model="model.label" name="dynamic" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!model.label" ng-click="onAddCheckBox()">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="checkbox col-lg-12" ng-repeat="checkBox in checkBoxes track by $index">
            <input type="checkbox" name="name_{{$index}}" id="name_{{$index}}" ng-model="checkBox.selectedCheckBox" class="filled-in square chk-col-pink ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" checked="checked" aria-invalid="false">
            <label for="checkBox.label">{{checkBox.label}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function init() {
    $scope.isEnableTextBox = false;
    $scope.checkBoxes = [];
    $scope.model = {};
}

$scope.onEnable = function onEnable() {
    $scope.isEnableTextBox = true; // Enable text box on Click Plus Icon
};

$scope.onAddCheckBox = function onAddCheckBox() { // On submit button click push the given name into array and empty the text box. Please refer the attached image.
    var _checkBoxModel = angular.copy($scope.model.label);
    $scope.model.label = "";
    $scope.checkBoxes.push({'label': _checkBoxModel, 'selectedCheckBox': true});
};

init();
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oMl9.png)